# Array not showing up on console

Tags: javascript

I have no clue why this code doesn't work.

```
var tipCalculator = [1.2,1.15,1.10];
var restaurantBills = [124,48,738,10,300,150];
var finalBills = [];

function calculateBills(){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < restaurantBills.length ;  i++){

        switch(true){
            case restaurantBills[i]<50:
                finalBills.push(restaurantBills[i]*tipCalculator[0]);
                break;
            case restaurantBills[i]>50 && restaurantBills[i]<200 :
                finalBills.push(restaurantBills[i]*tipCalculator[1]);
                break;
            case restaurantBills[i]>200:
                finalBills.push(restaurantBills[i]*tipCalculator[2]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        };
    };

return finalBills;};

console.log(calculateBills);
```

Comment: You never *call* the function. Then the function gets its input from global state, not parameters, and doesn't deal with bills of exactly 50 or 200 dollars.

Comment: calculateBills is a function and you are not executing it.... your console should clearly show the function reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: What exactly is `switch(true){` suppose to be

Comment: to add to the above -- you need to add `()` to call a function for example: `calculateBills()`

Comment: yes i totally missed the () at the end. thank you epascarello

Comment: @AlonEitan it is a bad practice (in most people's eyes) way of using it like if statements.

Comment: @AlonEitan `switch (true) { case condition: ...` will run the first `case` where `condition` evaluates to true.

Comment: @epascarello Oh, I have never seen it before, good to know

Comment: @AlonEitan you tell me , that's what was shown in the course im taking and its working after i added the ()  i forgot in the last line

Comment: @epascarello is it considered a bad practice because of runtime issues?

Comment: @chris I don't think it causes any runtime issues, but usually switch statements contain the expression to evaluate in the brackets, and then each case is a possible value. Using it in reverse like you are can be a little confusing to read at first.

Answer (score 1):

calculate bills is a function and so must be called

calculateBills();

then your code should be fine

Comment: You should use code notation in your answer like ```caculateBills()``` to indicate your piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by *jonrsharpe* you never called the function that is returning the array. 
To make a function *execute* you need to **call** it.

change the line from

```
console.log(calculateBills);
```

to

```
console.log(calculateBills());
```

for debugging 
Browsers like Chrome and Firefox comes with javascript debugger. Goto dev tools -> debugger where you would be able to set break points and trace the execution of your code. 
[Get Started with Debugging JavaScript in Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)  
[How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)